# Storage acces framework vs Mediastore api

Tags: android, mediastore, scoped-storage

can anyone help me to understand difference between SAF and mediastore api. Since both can be use to read and write file.

Comment: Just reading and experimenting with code will bring you the difference soon.

Comment: `Since both can be use to read and write file.` Well no. The media store is just a database of all files on your device. You can get an uri for a file. Thats all. But reading and writing you have to do yourself (using that uri).

Comment: So  i can use SAF to browse media/non media files And media store api can be use to query media/non media files. I am right?

Comment: You can use saf to browse the storage locations of your device discovering files of all types on your device. You can do the same with the media store. But doing so you need quite different code and sometimes one is handy and sometimes the other. SAF preserves the folder structure you see using classic file means. Mediastore tries to obscure that folder structure which makes it hard to handle many times.

Answer (score 2):

**Storage Access Framework**: It is primarily used to access non-media files eg .pdf etc

**Media store API**: It is used to access Media Files mainly but you can also access non-media too. eg. Images, Video, etc.

Comment: thanks  saurabh,   but if  i can access media file like image using SAF , then why to use media store api.

Comment: SAF allows the user to select images one or many depends but they are located on different directories so it will be inconvenient for the user if you use SAF While Media store gives all files from directories in recycler view which will be convenient to user